# What is the most power/energy efficient sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, efficiency, power-consumption

I am writing a Android phone application that needs to be very power efficient, and I would like to use the most power efficient sorting algorithm. I will implement it in C for extra power efficiency. What algorithm is the most power efficient algorithm for sorting arbitrary text strings?

Comment: I suspect that depends heavily on your architecture. Do you know what operations are most/least expensive for ARM?

Comment: Also, are you sorting large quantities of data? Do you have any evidence to suggest that sorting is the power-bottleneck in your app? Always profile before you optimize.

Comment: Well then it could even depend on the exact ARM chip so I probably need a more generic answer?

Comment: Define "arbitrary". Do you know anything about your inputs?

Comment: By the way, the sentence "I will implement it in C for extra power efficiency." rings several alarm bells. Are you such a good C programmer that you are sure to make a better job than several decades of library development?

Comment: OK, I'll say something that should have been said already: please, please, for the sake of whatever deities you pray to, please, do not choose a sorting algorithm at this stage based on its energy efficiency. Write your entire end-to-end application using the most standard method first, and only then should you possibly consider changing the sorting algorithm if during performance testing you detect a measurable inefficiency. This stands naked on the roof and screams "premature optimization".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As concluded by [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6224256&sortType%3Dasc_p_Sequence%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A6224250%29), the algorithm with the better asymptotic run time seems
to also have the better energy efficiency, which corroborates the assumption that an algorithm with a higher performance also has a higher energy efficiency.

Comment: Not true, at least generally. 1) As far as I can tell from skimming it, the paper does not consider the effect instrumentation may have. 2) "Better asymptotic runtime" is not the same as "better $O$-class". If one compares $O(n \log n)$ sorting algorithms, things become more interesing (see [my answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13563/98)).

Answer (score 5):

Smaller runtime is not all. In [Evaluating Algorithms according to their Energy Consumption](http://wwwagak.cs.uni-kl.de/downloads/papers/Evaluating_Algorithms_according_to_their_Energy_Consumption.pdf) (Computability in Europe, 2009), Fudeus née Bayer and Nebel show that an algorithm with more executed instructions (this is typically analysed, at least in theory) might use less energy¹.

Keep in mind that energy consumption is determined by at least

- the algorithm itself,
- the compiler,
- the CPU and
- the hardware memory management.

One particular effect is that the energy consumption of modern CPUs is not just the sum of fixed contributions of all statements. The *sequence* is relevant, that is an addition may have different cost depending on whether it is executed after a jump or a subtraction. Hence, for example

- instruction reordering by the compiler can have effects in all directions on energy consumption, depending on the target system, and
- fewer operations cost more because e.g. the ALU is shut down in between operations and is costly to start up again.

---

1. It might also be faster, mind.

Comment: Cache friendliness is a **huge** consideration. Not only does accessing more distant parts of the memory hierarchy use more energy but some energy is consumed by the system even when just waiting for a memory access to complete. By the way, more executed instructions is **not** the same as longer runtime; e.g., branch mispredictions, lack of ILP, and cache misses can make a shorter execution trace take longer to execute. Given static power consumption in non-sleep state, faster is often more energy efficient.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton All true. FWIW, Fudeus and Nebel investigate "true" runtime and the "paradox" still occurs.

Answer (score 3):

The [sort benchmark](http://sortbenchmark.org/) website has a category on energy efficient sorting. Currently, [NTOSort](http://sortbenchmark.org/NTOSort2013.pdf) and [Tritonsort](http://sortbenchmark.org/2011_06_tritonsort.pdf) seem to be the best.